# Is it a good method that specifying Max poolsize in a connection string to restrict databse access?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

if I mention maxpool size(say 50) in a webservice(asmx) connection string ,At each webservice call  is it create a new connection with pool size 50 one or use connection from already allocated pool?

Is it a good method that specifying Max poolsize in a connection string to restrict databse access?